# Selenium webdriver - Not able to set browser locale

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to set the browser locale to Japanese. I am using the following piece of code :

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
//setting the locale japanese : ‘ja’
profile.setPreference(“intl.accept_languages”,”ja”);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

"intl" is not recognized on the eclipse editor. It says "intl" cannot be resolved to a local variable. Eclipse does not suggest any imports either. It asks me to create a local variable "intl".

I dont know any other way to go about this. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your quotes should be fixed. Replace:

```
profile.setPreference(“intl.accept_languages”,”ja”);
```

with:

```
profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "ja");
```